# How to segment 2 regions after applying Difference of Gaussians (DoG)?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, scikit-image

I have the following image:

[image]

In order to detect edges, I have applied Difference of Gaussians (DoG), which yielded sharper edges than gradient based filters.

```py
from skimage import filters

smooth = filters.median(image_slice, morphology.disk(9))
filtered_image = filters.difference_of_gaussians(smooth,0.5,2)
```

Output:

[image]

**The desired edges are fairly noticeable. How can I now obtain the contours, and segment with a polygon?**

Desired output:

[image]

Comment: Use Canny edges on your DoG result. But how would you distinguish between one bone and the other. They both have similar strength edges and also textures. Physically, what separates the two. If you cannot answer that, then I do not think there is an easy solution apart from training with lots of images and then AI/Deep Learning approach.

Comment: @fmw42 Using canny on the DoG image is returning a black image, I guess no edges are being detected

Comment: The Canny detector has several parameters to tweak. Tweak them appropriately and you will detect something. Whether it is exactly what you need is something you can only know if you try.